# UICollectionview view in cell incorrect drawing

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am writing a chat application for Apple-tv, and I have a problem with displaying custom view in cells chat.

I have code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
        UICollectionViewCell {
            var myCell = self.chatCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(chatCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
            myCell.removeFromSuperview()
                currentIndexPath = indexPath
                if flag[indexPath.row]==0
                {
                myCell = sendBotMessage(historyString[indexPath.row], path: indexPath, collectionView: chatCollectionView)
                }
                else
                {
                myCell = sendUserMessage(historyString[indexPath.row], path: indexPath, collectionView: chatCollectionView)
                }
            return myCell
    }
```

Code displays two versions of messages, as can be seen, `sendBotMessage` and `sendUserMessage`. The problem is that the display of the next cell is rendered incorrectly previous. First run with 1 sendBotMessage-view
[image: first run]
and after adding second item
[image: second run]
second (right) messages adding by `sendUserMessage`, another view.
the whole history of "correspondence" is stored in `historyString` - an array of type string. Storage is organized correctly , as when scrolling display errors disappear. For this reason, it can be concluded about the correctness of the rendering functions .
All new message appends in `historyString`, after that calling `reloadData()` and `collectionView` must be redrawing.

Where I could make a mistake? I tried to clean the `subview` for `collectionView`, disable scrolling animation, it did not help.

Code of procedure drawing view's :

```
    func sendUserMessage(text : String, path : NSIndexPath, collectionView : UICollectionView) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let userMessage = text
        let textSize = getTextFrameSize(userMessage)
        let frameForMessage = getFrameforView(textSize) 

        let messageBuble = Chat_ViewInCell(frame: frameForMessage, textSize: textSize, text: userMessage)
        messageBuble.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        let avatarImage = UIImage(named: "\(userAvatar+1).png")
        let avatarView = UIImageView(image: avatarImage)
        avatarView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

        let totalX = messageBuble.frame.width + 340
        let constraint = 1750 - totalX
        messageBuble.frame.origin = CGPointMake(constraint, 0)
        avatarView.frame = CGRectMake(messageBuble.frame.maxX + 10, 0, 170, 170)

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(chatCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: path) as! chatCollectionViewCell
        //добавляем, счастье, радуемся
        cell.addSubview(messageBuble)
        cell.addSubview(avatarView)
        return cell
    }
func sendBotMessage(text : String, path : NSIndexPath, collectionView : UICollectionView) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let userMessage = text
        let textSize = getTextFrameSize(userMessage)
        let frameForMessage = getFrameforView(textSize) 

        let messageBuble = bot_ViewInCell(frame: frameForMessage, textSize: textSize, text: userMessage)
        messageBuble.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        let avatarImage = UIImage(named: partner_image)
        let avatarView = UIImageView(image: avatarImage)
        avatarView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        avatarView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 170, 170)
        let constraint = avatarView.frame.maxX + 10
        messageBuble.frame.origin = CGPointMake(constraint, 0)

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(chatCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: path) as! chatCollectionViewCell
        //добавляем в возвращаемую ячейку
        cell.addSubview(avatarView)
        cell.addSubview(messageBuble)
        return cell
    }
```

After recommended changes with custom CollectionCellView i have this code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UICollectionViewCell {
        var myCell = chatCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(chatCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! chatCollectionViewCell
        var customCell = myCell
            if flag[indexPath.row]==0
            {
            customCell = sendBotMessage(historyString[indexPath.row], path: indexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
            }
            else
            {
            customCell = sendUserMessage(historyString[indexPath.row], path: indexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
            }
        myCell = customCell
        currentIndexPath = indexPath
        return myCell
}
```

Function on drawing too have changes to custom cell:

```
    func sendUserMessage(text : String, path : NSIndexPath, collectionView : UICollectionView) -> chatCollectionViewCell {

    let userMessage = text
    let textSize = getTextFrameSize(userMessage) //высчитали необходимые размеры лейбла
    let frameForMessage = getFrameforView(textSize) //высчиитали необходимые размеры всей вьюшки

    let messageBuble = Chat_ViewInCell(frame: frameForMessage, textSize: textSize, text: userMessage)
    messageBuble.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    //создаем аватар
    let avatarImage = UIImage(named: "\(userAvatar+1).png")
    let avatarView = UIImageView(image: avatarImage)
    avatarView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

    //считаем отступ до правого края, позицию аватара
    let totalX = messageBuble.frame.width + 340
    let constraint = 1750 - totalX
    messageBuble.frame.origin = CGPointMake(constraint, 0)
    avatarView.frame = CGRectMake(messageBuble.frame.maxX + 10, 0, 170, 170)

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(chatCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: path) as! chatCollectionViewCell
    //добавляем, счастье, радуемся
    cell.addSubview(messageBuble)
    cell.addSubview(avatarView)
    return cell
}

    func sendBotMessage(text : String, path : NSIndexPath, collectionView : UICollectionView) -> chatCollectionViewCell {

    let userMessage = text
    let textSize = getTextFrameSize(userMessage) //высчитали необходимые размеры лейбла
    let frameForMessage = getFrameforView(textSize) //высчиитали необходимые размеры всей вьюшки

    //создали всю вьюшку
    let messageBuble = bot_ViewInCell(frame: frameForMessage, textSize: textSize, text: userMessage)
    messageBuble.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    //создаем аватар и считаем его позицию
    let avatarImage = UIImage(named: partner_image)
    let avatarView = UIImageView(image: avatarImage)
    avatarView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    avatarView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 170, 170)
    let constraint = avatarView.frame.maxX + 10
    messageBuble.frame.origin = CGPointMake(constraint, 0)

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(chatCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: path) as! chatCollectionViewCell
    //добавляем в возвращаемую ячейку
    cell.addSubview(avatarView)
    cell.addSubview(messageBuble)
    return cell
}
```

But problem no fixes... What i makes wrong with custom CollectionViewCell? I must to do smth another?

Comment: Don't `removeFromSuperView`, and show the code of `sendBotMessage()` and `sendUserMessage()`. My guess: you have an issue with reuse of cells. In `sendBotMessage()` and ``sendUserMessage()` you may have to clean the cell there.

Comment: added sendBotMessage and sendUserMessage

Comment: Use a custom UICollectionViewCell, don't add subview eachtime to your collectionViewCell. Cells are reused.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed! I don't know about prepareForReuse() method. So simple, in custom cell class defeniton i must override it method, and call for subviews clearsContextBeforeDrawing and removeFromSuperview. Code here:

```
class chatCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var view: Chat_ViewInCell!

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    for currView in self.subviews
    {
        currView.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = true
        currView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

All worked, without incorrect redrawing.